# SEO url with hyphen - Nodejs

Tags: node.js, express, url

I have a situation where i want to create filters for my nodejs application. 
I want to filter products based on location, my current filter is something like below.

```
www.example.com/product-category?q=New%20York
```

But i want like this.

```
www.example.com/product-category/new-york
```

How can i achieve this via NodeJS/Express/Mongodb

Comment: what does your express route look like?

Comment: `router.get('/:slug/', function (req, res, next) {}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## The router

To get the *"category"* as an *url parameter* instead of a *query parameters*, we need to change the syntax a bit

- *Query param:* `router.get('/someRoute')`. Then call it with `GET /someRoute?city=paris`
- *URL param:* `router.get('/someRoute/:city')`. And we call it with `GET /someRoute/paris`

So in your case, the way to go is:

```
app.get('/product-category/:city', (req, res) => {
  // Handle the request here

  const city = req.params.city;
});
```

## The `%20` issue

In the case of *New York*, the API call includes a **space character** which is *"encoded"* into a `%20`. If you want to transform that into a *hyphen* you can use:

- [`String.toLowerCase()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/toLowerCase) to lowercase all characters (Seattle => seattle)
- [`String.split()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) to decompose the URL into blocks separated by `%20`
- [`Array.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) to remove any *"empty/whitespace"* block
- [`Array.join()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) to rebuild the URL by stitching the blocks with *hyphens* `-`

Bringing those parts together will look like this

```js
const cities = ['New York', 'New%20York', '     New     york', '\tnew York'];

const format = s => s.toLowerCase()
                     .split(/\s|%20/)
                     .filter(Boolean)
                     .join('-');
                     
const clean = cities.map(format);

console.log(clean);
```

## Bringing everything together

```
const format = s => s.toLowerCase()
                     .split(/\s|%20/)
                     .filter(Boolean)
                     .join('-');

app.get('/product-category/:city', (req, res) => {
  // Get and format the "city" parameter
  const city = format(req.params.city);
});
```